# Webpack hot module replacement through Django template

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to set up hot module replacement for my bundled frontend static assets that are served through Django's template system, if that's even possible. I'm currently refreshing the page via livereload whenever the compiled assets are changed, but the compile times are getting longer and any CSS changes end up triggering a full page reload.

Here is an example of the template file in Django.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Header Links -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.CONFIG = {
        /** Injected application configuration from Django. */
      };
    </script>

    <!-- Webpack bundle url -->
    <script src="{{ bundle_url }}"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I've been able to serve the assets through webpack dev server and inject the bundle url `http://localhost:3000/bundle.js` through template variables, so I can see the application in the view.

**Webpack Configuration**

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const CONFIG = require('./config');

/**
 * Webpack configuration for a development environment.
 * @type {Object}
 */
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('core-js/shim'),
    CONFIG.PATHS.ENTRY,
  ],
  output: {
    path: CONFIG.PATHS.BUILD,
    filename: CONFIG.OUTPUT_FILENAME,
  },
  module: {
    rules: CONFIG.SHARED_RULES.concat([{
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    }]),
  },
  resolve: CONFIG.WEBPACK_RESOLVE,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

**Start Script:**

```
'use strict';

// Crashes the script on unhandled rejections instead of silently ignoring.
process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => { throw error; });

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

// Vendor
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const chalk = require('chalk');

// Local
const WEBPACK_CONFIG = require('../config/webpack.config.dev');
const CONFIG = require('../config/config');

const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || CONFIG.DEFAULT_PORT;
const HOST = process.env.HOST || CONFIG.DEFAULT_HOST;
const URL = `http://${HOST}:${PORT}/`;

const compiler = webpack(WEBPACK_CONFIG);
const server = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  compress: true,
  hot: true,
  host: HOST,
  stats: 'minimal',
});

server.listen(PORT, HOST, (error) => {
  if (error) { return console.log(chalk.red(error)); }

  console.log(chalk.cyan(`Starting the development server at ${URL}...`));


  ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach((signal) => {
    process.on(signal, () => {
      server.close();
      process.exit();
    });
  });
});
```

I'm uncertain how the dev server triggers a hot reload. I was under the impression that the bundle includes a script that connects to a Websocket connection on the dev server and that the connection would trigger the script to download and display the new assets. This may not be the case though, and I haven't been able to find any info pertaining to how hot reloads are communicated. I've only found a general overview of how hot reloads work once the client receives the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I finally found a solution to my problem. I found [information about how to integrate webpack-dev-server with an existing server in the old webpack docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#combining-with-an-existing-server), so I got rid of the entire build script and replaced it with a script in `package.json` that only used webpack-dev-server without any flags at all:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
  // Scripts...
}
```

This automatically injected the hot module replacement code into my bundle and refreshes my page on a change. This is much faster than my previous livereload server. The bundle is referenced via the url `http:localhost:8080/bundle.js` in my application template and not by a local path. Local paths wouldn't work anyways since the bundles are saved in memory.

The url also explains how to get the `--inline --hot` functionality working too, but I was never able to get it to work on my setup.

If you need to use local path's instead of referencing the bundles via url, than you would have to rely on using webpack's watch mode and manually refreshing the page or rely on a Django plugin. The solution I found worked well for me because it mirrors our production environment. Our Django deployment references the frontend assets through a CDN that we manage. It may not work well for you if you have to deploy the frontend assets with your Django code, but it's possible if you create a Django setting that toggles between two different application templates: one for development that uses the URL to pull in the script and one for production that references the files from the `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I don't think is Webpack's fault. I've noticed these speed problems occur when I had Django serve my React files. When you use Django, your files are served by the Django server, and that inherently is pretty slow compared to the webpack-dev server. The whole communication process between webpack dev server to Django can be time taking, which has to have the Django server to trigger a change and then re-serve the static files again.

One solution to this would be to isolate React front end code from the backend code and have your React consume your Django's REST API. It runs extremely smooth and reduces a lot of load on the server.

Comment: I'm already doing that. The frontend and backend projects are in two completely separate repositories and the frontend assets are served through a URL (http://localhost:3000/bundle.js) from webpack-dev-server instead of a local file path (path/to/bundle.js) in the application template. What I'm trying to figure out is if I can leverage webpack-dev-server's hot reload ability through that URL if the application's HTML template isn't served through webpack-dev-server.